# Organizar objeto em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
objTeste = [
  {
    "id": "03",
    "nome": "teste03",
    "pai": {
      "id": "02",
      "nome": "teste02",
      "pai": {
        "id": "01",
        "nome": "teste01"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "nome": "teste02",
    "pai": {
      "id": "01",
      "nome": "teste01"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "01",
    "nome": "teste01"
  }
]
```

Estou tentando organizar esse objeto pelo filho que traz seus parentes dentro dele,só que quero ignorar seus parentes na hora que for armazenar em outro objeto.

Exemplo:

Quero armazenar somente o objeto a seguir:

```
{
    "id": "03",
    "nome": "teste03",
    "pai": {
      "id": "02",
      "nome": "teste02",
      "pai": {
        "id": "01",
        "nome": "teste01"
      }
    }
  }
```

em outro objeto ignorando o restante do objTeste. Estou usando JavaScript para organizar esse objeto.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que queres dizer com "armazenar em outro objecto"? Para isolares esse objeto podes usar objTeste[0].

Comment: Que o novo objeto receba somente o objTeste[0] mais tem que verificar se ele tem parente, pois esse objeto poderá ser pai de outro futuramente aí terei que organizar ele novamente, trazendo somente o filho e seus parentes.

Comment: Ainda não entendi bem a sua dúvida, da forma que você armazena já não está salvando os pais dentro dos filhos?

Comment: Explica melhor a ideia que tens de parentes e filhos para ficar mais claro. Sem isso parece-me que isto chega: `var novoObjeto = objTeste[0];`

Comment: Quero ignorar os objetos parentes fora do filho, trazendo eles no objeto filho. Tenho que fazer essa organização usando um for??

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi bem, você não quer que elementos que já aparecem como pai de outro elemento estejam presentes como elementos no vetor principal, evitando repetir elementos.

Se for isto mesmo, pode fazer em dois passos:

1. Percorra todos os elementos e armazene quais são pais de outros elementos
2. Elimine do vetor aqueles que forem pais, portanto já aparecem em outro elemento

A função abaixo faz isso:

```
function normalizar(vetor) {
    //construir um mapa com elementos que são pai 
    var mapa = {};
    function indexarItem(item) {
        if ('pai' in item) {
            mapa[item['pai']['id']] = item['id'];
            indexarItem(item['pai']);
        }
    }
    vetor.forEach(indexarItem);
    //remover elementos do vetor que sejam pai
    function naoEhPai(item) {
            return !(item['id'] in mapa);
    }
    return vetor.filter(naoEhPai);
}
```

Você pode ver o exemplo funcional no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/cazd7kzz/).

Comment: Obrigado! É isso mesmo que estava querendo fazer.

Answer (score 0):

este talvez não seja o seu caso, mas talvez você possa utilizar o [`cycle.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js), com ele você consegue apontar para uma referencia do objeto, e não objeto em sim.

Esta blibioteca tambem pode ser util caso queira fazer um `JSON.stringify` em um objeto com referencia circular.

```js
var pessoas = [  
  //pessoas[0]: "$ref": "$[0]"
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Nome": "Teste 01",
    "Conjugue": { "$ref": "$[1]" },
    "Pai": null,
    "Mae": null,
    "Filhos": [{ "$ref": "$[2]" }, { "$ref": "$[3]" }, { "$ref": "$[4]" } ],
    "Irmaos": null
  },
  //pessoas[1]: "$ref": "$[1]"
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Nome": "Teste 02",
    "Conjugue": { "$ref": "$[0]" },
    "Pai": null,
    "Mae": null,
    "Filhos":  [{ "$ref": "$[2]" }, { "$ref": "$[3]" }, { "$ref": "$[4]" } ],
    "Irmaos": null
  },
  //pessoas[2]: "$ref": "$[2]"
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Nome": "Teste 03",
    "Conjugue": null,
    "Pai": { "$ref": "$[0]" },
    "Mae": { "$ref": "$[1]" },
    "Filhos": null,
    "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "$[3]" }, { "$ref": "$[4]" }]
  },
  //pessoas[3]: "$ref": "$[3]"
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Nome": "Teste 04",
    "Conjugue": null,
    "Pai": { "$ref": "$[0]" },
    "Mae": { "$ref": "$[1]" },
    "Filhos": null,
    "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "$[2]" }, { "$ref": "$[4]" }]
  },
  //pessoas[4]: "$ref": "$[4]"
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Nome": "Teste 05",
    "Conjugue": null,
    "Pai": { "$ref": "$[0]" },
    "Mae": { "$ref": "$[1]" },
    "Filhos": null,
    "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "$[2]" }, { "$ref": "$[3]" }]
  }
];

var _pessoas = JSON.retrocycle(pessoas);

console.log(_pessoas);

console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(_pessoas)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/cycle.js"></script>
```

algumas blibiotecas server-side, como o [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) para `C#` fazem uso de uma abordagem semelhante para resolver problemas de referencia circular, porém neste caso o `$ref` não aponta para o Path do objeto, mas para o objeto com a propriedade `$id` com o mesmo valor.

em todo caso, você pode adaptar o script do [Douglas Crockfords](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) para trabalhar da mesma forma.

neste caso o json recebido seria algo semelhante a:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Pessoa
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Conjugue { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pai { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Mae { get; set; }
    public Pessoa[] Filhos { get; set; }
    public Pessoa[] Irmaos { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pessoas = new Pessoa[5];
        pessoas[0] = new Pessoa() { ID=  1, Nome = "Teste 01" };
        pessoas[1] = new Pessoa() { ID=  2, Nome = "Teste 02" };
        pessoas[2] = new Pessoa() { ID=  3, Nome = "Teste 03" };
        pessoas[3] = new Pessoa() { ID=  4, Nome = "Teste 04" };
        pessoas[4] = new Pessoa() { ID=  5, Nome = "Teste 05" };

        pessoas[0].Conjugue = pessoas[1];
        pessoas[0].Filhos = new Pessoa[] { pessoas[2], pessoas[3], pessoas[4] };

        pessoas[1].Conjugue = pessoas[0];
        pessoas[1].Filhos = new Pessoa[] { pessoas[2], pessoas[3], pessoas[4] };

        pessoas[2].Pai = pessoas[0];
        pessoas[2].Mae = pessoas[1];
        pessoas[2].Irmaos = new Pessoa[] { pessoas[3], pessoas[4] };

        pessoas[3].Pai = pessoas[0];
        pessoas[3].Mae = pessoas[1];
        pessoas[3].Irmaos = new Pessoa[] { pessoas[2], pessoas[4] };

        pessoas[4].Pai = pessoas[0];
        pessoas[4].Mae = pessoas[1];
        pessoas[4].Irmaos = new Pessoa[] { pessoas[2], pessoas[3] };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pessoas, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
        });
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        /*
        [  
          //pessoas[0]: "$ref": "1"
          {
            "ID": 1,
            "Nome": "Teste 01",
            "Conjugue": { "$ref": "2" },
            "Pai": null,
            "Mae": null,
            "Filhos": [{ "$ref": "3" }, { "$ref": "4" }, { "$ref": "5" } ],
            "Irmaos": null
          },
          //pessoas[1]: "$ref": "2"
          {
            "ID": 2,
            "Nome": "Teste 02",
            "Conjugue": { "$ref": "1" },
            "Pai": null,
            "Mae": null,
            "Filhos":  [{ "$ref": "3" }, { "$ref": "4" }, { "$ref": "5" } ],
            "Irmaos": null
          },
          //pessoas[2]: "$ref": "3"
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "Nome": "Teste 03",
            "Conjugue": null,
            "Pai": { "$ref": "1" },
            "Mae": { "$ref": "2" },
            "Filhos": null,
            "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "4" }, { "$ref": "5" }]
          },
          //pessoas[3]: "$ref": "4"
          {
            "ID": 4,
            "Nome": "Teste 04",
            "Conjugue": null,
            "Pai": { "$ref": "1" },
            "Mae": { "$ref": "2" },
            "Filhos": null,
            "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "3" }, { "$ref": "5" }]
          },
          //pessoas[4]: "$ref": "5"
          {
            "ID": 5,
            "Nome": "Teste 05",
            "Conjugue": null,
            "Pai": { "$ref": "1" },
            "Mae": { "$ref": "2" },
            "Filhos": null,
            "Irmaos": [{ "$ref": "3" }, { "$ref": "4" }]
          }
        ];
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É só pegar primeira estrutura do array:

```
var armazenado = objTeste[0];
```

E para usar esta estrutura:

```
var id = armazenado.id;
var nome = armazenado.nome;
var id_pai = armazenado.pai.id;
var nome_pai = armazenado.pai.nome;
```